# Angular module not available after grunt build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm fairly new to angular, grunt, bower, node and all this stuff, and I am facing a problem when trying to build my project using grunt.

I used the **angular-php** yeoman generator, that is based in **generator-angular**, and I have been developing using grunt serve without any problems.

The problem comes when I try to build the project for production with **grunt build**. The process works ok, but when I try to load the application, I get this error in the console:

```
vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10420 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lossanroquerApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=uiGmapgoogle-maps
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10420:12
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:12427:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:12351:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:12425:14)
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14960:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10673:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14944:5)
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14961:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10673:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14944:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=uiGmapgoogle-maps&p…0(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fscripts%2Fvendor.d4e4dfe8.js%3A14944%3A5)
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10420:12
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14983:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10673:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14944:5)
    at http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14961:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:10673:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14944:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:14866:19)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:12103:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8888/scripts/vendor.d4e4dfe8.js:12124:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=lossanroquerApp&p1=…(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fscripts%2Fvendor.d4e4dfe8.js%3A12124%3A12)
```

I made my investigation for why could this be happening, and I understand that angular is trying to load a module before it's defined/loaded. I checked the vendor.js file just in case the module were missing, but the module is in the script file. Also I have disabled the minification and uglify tasks to make sure there was nothing broken.

This error happens in various modules, because I tried to change the order of the scripts in the index.html and when I fix one, it happens to another.

Here is my actual index.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-tooltips/dist/angular-tooltips.min.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/welcome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/generic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/player.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/news.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/tour.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/discography.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/gallery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/video.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

      <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="lossanroquerApp">
      <div class="background-image" ng-class="[{true: 'bgtransition'}[welcome], {true: 'unblurred'}[fromWelcome]]"></div>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div id="mainView" class="{{pageClass}} fromWelcome-{{fromWelcome}}" transitionend="cleanFromWelcome" ui-view></div>
    <div class="playerMainContainer" ng-include="'views/player.html'" ></div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
       (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
       })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/animation-frame/AnimationFrame.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/shifty/dist/shifty.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rekapi/dist/rekapi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/spark-scroll/src/spark-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-fontawesome/dist/angular-fontawesome.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-core.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-classapplier.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-highlighter.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-serializer.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-textrange.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngularSetup.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/amplitude/js/amplitude.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-tooltips/dist/angular-tooltips.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/google-maps-utility-library-v3-markerwithlabel/dist/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/google-maps-utility-library-v3-infobox/dist/infobox.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/google-maps-utility-library-v3-keydragzoom/dist/keydragzoom.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/js-rich-marker/src/richmarker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-youtube-api-factory/dist/angular-youtube-api-factory.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-youtube-embed/src/ng-youtube-embed.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
      <script src="node_modules/angulargrid/angulargrid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->


        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/welcome.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/transitionend.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/home.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/player.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/newsservice.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/mobileonly.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/news.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/shows.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/tour.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/discography.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/albums.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/initamplitudeonlast.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/gallery.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/video.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/bio.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/contact.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/loading.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/gallery.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('lossanroquerApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router',
    'gilbox.sparkScroll',
    'picardy.fontawesome',
    '720kb.socialshare',
    '720kb.tooltips',
    'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
    'infinite-scroll',
    'angularGrid',
    'jtt_youtube',
    'ngYoutubeEmbed'
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }).hashPrefix('!');


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      });
  });

angular.module('infinite-scroll').value('THROTTLE_MILLISECONDS', 250);
```

And my Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2016-06-21 using generator-angular-php 0.6.3
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // grunt-connect-proxy middleware to serve PHP
  var proxyMiddleware = function (connect, options) {
    var middlewares = [];
    var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
    if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
      options.base = [options.base];
    }

    // Setup the proxy
    middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);

    options.base.forEach(function(base) {
      // Serve static files.
      middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
    });

    // Make directory browse-able.
    middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));

    return middlewares;
  };

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/api/{,{config,src,tests}/**/}/*',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      },
      phpTest: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/api/{,{config,src,tests}/**/}/*'],
        tasks: ['shell:phpTest']
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9024,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35742
      },
      proxies: [
        {
          context: '/api',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: '<%= php.options.port %>'
        }
      ],
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
              var optBase = (typeof options.base === 'string') ? [options.base] : options.base;
            return [
//              modRewrite([
//                '!\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\.png$ /index.html [L]'
//              ]),
                require('connect-modrewrite')([
                    '^/api/(.*) - [L]',
                    '.*/api/(.*) /api/$1',
                    '!(\\..+)$ /index.html ',
                ]) ,
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ].concat(proxyMiddleware(connect, options))
            .concat(optBase.map(function(path){ return connect.static(path); }));
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ].concat(proxyMiddleware(connect, options));
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          middleware: proxyMiddleware
        }
      }
    },

    // PHP built-in server
    php: {
      options: {
        port: 8000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '127.0.0.1',
        router: 'api/index.php'
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      options: {
        cwd: ''
      },
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /..\//
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat'/*, 'uglifyjs'*/],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            'api/{{config,src,vendor}/**,index.php,.htaccess}',
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.',
          src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    shell: {
      options: {
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true,
        failOnError: true
      },
      phpTest: {
        command: 'make --directory <%= yeoman.app %>/api test'
      },
      phpUpdate: {
        command: 'make --directory <%= yeoman.app %>/api update'
      }
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'build',
        'configureProxies',
        'php:dist',
        'connect:dist:keepalive'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'configureProxies',
      'php:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'shell:phpTest',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'shell:phpUpdate',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
//    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
//    'cdnify',
//    'cssmin',
//    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
//    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so finally I made a lot more of experiments and tests, and at last I found the problem. There was a conflict with a dependency version (lodash).
There were two dependencies, ui-google-maps and spark-scroll, that required two different versions of lodash, and somehow that was causing some modules to not be loaded properly. For now I have removed the ui-google-maps dependency and reinstalled my bower_components.

Comment: Is there an easy way two find the confilting dependencies? I run into the same problem, and my solution was to move the conflicting modules out of the ` <!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor.js -->` block.

Comment: @EmirHerrera, found no straight way to debug this. I removed the task that was uglifying my code and was able to get conflicting module info from the console. The solution was to change the version of the conflicting module.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen when the dependencies are not inline annotated.

For instance,

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('xCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
})
```

.. breaks after minification. But the following won't.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('xCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  }
])
```

Read in depth here - http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/angularjs-dependency-injection-demystified/

Comment: As can be seen in my Gruntfile.js, all the minification tasks are commented out and still the same error occurs.
Just in case, I added inline annotations for every controller. No luck.

Comment: @donkikote https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1489 might help you.

Comment: thank you but this has nothing to do with this specific module, if I remove the dependency from my app module, then another one fails

Comment: Could you share plnkr URI?